# General moderators' strike

Tags: discussion, moderators, psa

Open letter here: https://openletter.mousetail.nl

I haven't decided what I think about this yet.
It seemed fairly apparent months ago that technical support was a prime target for ChatGPT et al., and this *is* a technical support WWW site.

The question of whether this will affect this WWW site, that I *was* going to post, has already been answered; as the signatures list on the letter grew as I was writing this question.

So at this point this is more of a public service announcement than a question.

There's a whole lot more at [Sustainability of new AI generated content policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389742/167145) and a fair number of other meta places, too, for the curious.

Comment: Not only moderators, by the way. All users are more than welcome to participate and abstain from their regular curation of content across the network.

Comment: For those looking for a quick summary, an ex-SE employee, Jon Ericson, has provided a far more objective one than I would have been able to: https://jlericson.com/2023/05/31/mod_strike

Comment: Also related: [What has happened to lead moderators to consider striking?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424979)

Comment: I have to assume posts _about_ the strike are exempt from the actions under "I am not a moderator on any stack exchange site, how can I help?"?

Comment: I don’t know about this particular SE site, but as far as I’m concerned, **SE sites are not support sites at all**.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship if by "support" you mean this is a place to come to ask for help when your OS isn't behaving as you expect, then yes, this site is very much a support site. As are [ubuntu.se], [apple.se], [su] and a bunch of others. Yes, we expect users to put in some effort first, and yes, we also get annoyed if the question seems to just be a brain dump of the questioner, but if someone has tried to solve it themselves (to the limits of their knowledge, we welcome newbies here) and then comes to ask for help, we are happy to give support.

Answer (score 2):

This strike effort seems to have come to an end: [Moderation strike: Conclusion and the way forward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392032/moderation-strike-conclusion-and-the-way-forward), which points out:

> However, each individual will have to decide for themselves if the result is satisfactory enough to stop striking on an individual level; the coordinated call to strike has ended, but nobody involved has the authority to bind any individual into striking or not